# build a timeline for an IP Camera captured images

Tags: javascript, timeline

I want to build a timeline/timeslider to show the captured ip camera images.
The images will be searched and the result of the search will be saved as events (with image capture Datetime) in a json object :

```
{
  {
   id:"1",   
   startDate: "DateTime of the capture",
   url: "source of the image"
  },
  {
   id:"2",
   startDate: "DateTime of the capture"
   url: "source of the image"
  }
   ...  

}
```

with this json object i want to build a Timeline/timeslider with playback.
I found a plugin that´s exactly what i'm looking for, but it only works with GeoJSON objects to replay GPS Tracks.

[leafletplayback](http://leafletplayback.theoutpost.io/examples/example_1.html)

has anyone an idea how to build this timeline/timeslider ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using Timeline JS3 that will be able to create timelines from the JSON format. You will have to change your JSON format to match the format that is required by Timeline JS3.

https://timeline.knightlab.com